# pandas sparse dataframe head error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dummy-variable

I am trying to get see the head of a sparse dataframe created using get_dummies.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(f_loc, sep = " ")
print df.head()
data = pd.get_dummies(df,sparse=True)
print data.head()
```

It gives me the error

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1703, in __init__
    raise TypeError("values must be {0}".format(self._holder.__name__))
```

Comment: I cannot simulate, what is `print type(data)` ?

Comment: it is <class 'pandas.core.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame'>, @jezrael

Comment: Hmmm, what about `data[:5]` ?

Comment: @jezrael.  [5 rows x 11067 columns]

Comment: Maybe problem is you are out of memory, so get weird errors :(

Comment: isn't it weird ?. It should simply say "Memory Error", right ?. Moreover, I got 128GB of RAM with 2GB swap.

Comment: Ya, you are right. But another alternatives failed too? What is your pandas version?

Comment: yes, alternatives also failed.  I got pandas 0.21. I read it uses unit8 for dummy variables.  So memory should be fine i think.  On the other hand, shape of my dataframe is (6538581, 11067)

Comment: Only idea, if use `df = pd.read_csv(f_loc, sep = "\s+", nrows=1000)` - only first 100 rows of data it failed too?

Comment: yes.  I still get the errors for first 1000 rows.  But if I omit the sparse=True keyword, I get the required results for first 1000 rows, but for the full set of rows I get Memory Error. @jezrael

Comment: I am thinking a lot but no idea. So if use `print data` it return something?

Answer (score 0):

In last version of pandas (`0.21.0`) it working nice, but some alternatives should works:

```
np.random.seed(1997)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4))
df.iloc[:-97] = np.nan
data = df.to_sparse()

print (type(data))
<class 'pandas.core.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame'>

print (data.head())
          0        1         2         3
0       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
2       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
3  1.938422  1.78731 -0.619745 -2.560187
4 -0.986231 -1.94293  2.677379 -1.813071

print (data.iloc[:5])
          0        1         2         3
0       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
2       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
3  1.938422  1.78731 -0.619745 -2.560187
4 -0.986231 -1.94293  2.677379 -1.813071

print (data[:5])
          0        1         2         3
0       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
2       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
3  1.938422  1.78731 -0.619745 -2.560187
4 -0.986231 -1.94293  2.677379 -1.813071
```